# Как найти последнюю запись выборки?

Tags: orm, kohana

Т.е. что-то вроде:

```
ORM::factory('user')->where('lastname','=','Вованыч')->find_last()
```

Только что-то не вижу этого в доках.

**Решение**

```
ORM::factory('user')->where('lastname','=','Вованыч')
->order_by('id','desc')
->offset(0)
->limit(1)
->find();
```

Answer (score 2):

Я, конечно, могу ошибаться но разве запись вида: `ORM::factory('user')->where('lastname','=','Вованыч');`

не должна возвращать массив записей? Если это так, то почему бы не отсортировать этот массив(например по id) и обратиться к последнему элементу этого массива?

Можно прям вот так:

```
end(ORM::factory('user')->where('lastname','=','Вованыч'));
```

P.S. 
Кохану совсем не знаю и в глаза не разу не видел. В PHP тоже не селен. Но я на 78% уверен, что так можно сделать...

Comment: Любопытно, будет ли в таком подходе из базы вытаскиваться только один элемент?

Comment: не знаю даже, не получилось попробовать. Я решил раньше чем ответ увидел.

Comment: Думаю все таки из базы будут выбираться все элементы. А для того чтобы выбирались не все то можно использовать "limit".

Comment: тогда решение напишите вдруг кто то ищет

Answer (score 1):

Вам по какому параметру последняя нужна?

по дате:

```
ORM::factory('model_name')->order_by('date', 'desc')->find();
```

остальное по аналогии ;)